# Issues installing whonix on top of kicksecure

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kernel

I do not know anything about linux however I have been working on this problem for about 20 hours.

I have a Lenovo thinkpad T430s i installed Debian 12, and I am quite certain I have installed kicksecure sucessfully, however when I try to 'update' kicksecure to whonix I get the message

```
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [WARN]: VirtualBox Kernel Module Loaded Test Result: 'no' - file /dev/vboxdrv does not exist. This probably means that the vboxdrv kernel module has not been load yet.
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [NOTICE]: Running: $ sudo -- modprobe vboxdrv
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [NOTICE]: Virtualization Support Test: Your CPU supports virtualization: 'intel': 'vmx'
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [NOTICE]: Existing VM Check: Virtual Machine(s) have been imported previously.
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [NOTICE]: Available guest: 'Whonix-Gateway-Xfce'
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [NOTICE]: Available guest: 'Whonix-Workstation-Xfce'
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [WARN]: Debugging information:
Secure Boot Status: 'disabled' (mokutil_output: 'EFI variables are not supported on this system')
Kernel module has been load: false
Kernel module can be load: true (modules can be load. (sysctl kernel.modules_disabled=0 is set.)
Only signed kernel modules can be load: false
Kernel module vboxdrv signer: DKMS module signing key
kernel_module_modprobe_output (sudo modprobe vboxdrv): 
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [ERROR]: VirtualBox Installation Result: 'FAIL' - because kernel module load have not been load yet.
  - Kernel modules can be load in theory, should be loaded by now, but are not.
  - This is a VirtualBox installation issue.
whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [ERROR]: Virtual Machine Startup Result: FAIL
  - The installer succeeded with download and import, but
  - failed to start the virtual machines (VMs).
  - The root cause for this issue is likely not the installer.
  - This issue would likely also happen if the user tried to manually start the VMs.
  - This is likely happening due to the virtualization related warnings that have been reported above.
  - Resolving these issues (as per documentation hyperlinks above) would likely resolve this issue.
  https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox/Troubleshooting
```

I am guessing that the first problem to solve is `whonix-xfce-installer-cli: [WARN]: VirtualBox Kernel Module Loaded Test Result: 'no' - file`

But I am not sure how to do that.